# geom_rect missing when converting ggplot2 to ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to put together a `ggplotly` graph with three elements (`geom_point`, `geom_line`, and `geom_rect`) and it looks fine in `ggplot2`. However, when I convert to ggplotly, the geom_rect disappears. I'm thinking it's something with the `inherit.aes` function?

The code to build the test data is below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dates_seq = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-03-13"), as.Date("2019-04-21"), by = "1 day")
df = data.frame(ds = dates_seq,
                y = rnorm(length(dates_seq), mean = 50, sd = 5),
                yhat = rnorm(length(dates_seq), mean = 50, sd = 5)
                )
df$yhat_lower = df$yhat - 5
df$yhat_upper = df$yhat + 5

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ds, y = y)) +
    labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Sales') +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yhat_lower, ymax = yhat_upper), fill = 'blue',
                  alpha = 0.2,
                  na.rm = TRUE)

start_date = as.Date("2019-04-19")
gg <- gg +
  geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date(start_date - lubridate::days(1))), linetype = 2, color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = yhat), color = 'blue',
            na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_classic()

promo_df = data.frame(xmin = c("2019-03-15", "2019-04-01"), xmax = c("2019-03-18", "2019-04-08"),
                          ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, Promo = "Yes")
promo_df$id = 1:nrow(promo_df)
gg = gg +
  geom_rect(data=promo_df, inherit.aes=FALSE,
            aes(xmin=as.Date(xmin),
                xmax=as.Date(xmax),
                ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,
                group=id, fill = factor(Promo)), alpha=0.2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "On Promo?")
```

The ggplot image shows the desired output with the `geom_rect`.

```
gg
```

[image]

And now the ggplotly version:

```
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the `ggplotly` image to look like the basic `ggplot2` chart?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem you did - it appears to originate from the fact that `ggplotly` doesn't support `ymin = -Inf` and `ymax = Inf`. I haven't figured out a workaround yet, but will post an answer if I do!

Comment: Thanks @Clara! I'll do the same

Answer (score 3):

Clara is right with respect to ggplotly's inability to support the ymin/max parameters. The best work around is to just manually set the parameters equal to the scale of your previous (main) layer. So in this case, it would be equal to 0/65.